# BIRT Scripted Data Source using existing JDBC DataSource

Tags: jdbc, birt

I know that my overall problem is generally approached using two of the more common solutions such as a join data set or a sub-table, sub-report.  I have looked at those and I am not sure this will work effectively.

Background:
JDBC data source has local data which includes a series of id's that reference a record in a master data repository interfaced via a web service.  This is where the need for a scripted data source arises.  The data can be filtered on either attributes within the local JDBC data and/or the extended data from the web service.  The complication is that my only interface is the id argument to the webservice.

Ideal Solution:
Aside from creating a reporting table or other truly desirable scenarios I am looking to creating a unified data source through a single scripting data source that will handle all the complexities.  This leaves the report generation and parameter creation a bit cleaner, hopefully.  The idea is to leverage the JDBC query as well as the web service queries in the scripted data source do the filtering and joins and create that singular unified view.

I tried using the following code as a reference to use the existing JDBC connection in the BIRT report definition to execute the query.  However if I think my breakdown on what should be in open vs fetch given this came from beforeFactory for a completely different purpose may be giving me errors...truth is I see no errors it just returns 0 records.
[a link](http://developer.actuate.com/community/devshare/_/designing-birt-reports/1542-data-engine-api-to-check-data-set-values/)

I have also found a code snippet to dynamically load a JDBC connection but that seems a bit obtuse and a ton of overhead for what I am needing to do. [a link](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/17800-scripted-data-source-using-sql-entirely-in-rhino/?p=111955)

In short:  How in all-that-is-holy do you simply run a query against a database within a scripted data source if you wanted to do.  The merit of doing that is another issue, but technically how?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Tough question - looks like BIRT designer does not give you access to reportContext variable inside scripted datasource or dataset.  Have you considered building a JAR that has classes that do all the work for you, drop the JAR on your server, and have your scripted data source invoke your worker classes?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve?